# CppUnit: Why does a static local variable keep its value?

Tags: c++, oop, static, initialization, cppunit

I'm trying to use CppUnit to test a method that should execute some code only the first time it is called.

```
class CElementParseInputTests: public CppUnit::TestFixture {
private:
    CElement* element;
public:

    void setUp() {
        element = new CElement();
    }

    void tearDown() {
        delete element;
    }

    void test1() {
        unsigned int parsePosition = 0;
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(false, element->parseInput("fäil", parsePosition));
    }

    void test2() {
        unsigned int parsePosition = 0;
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(false, element->parseInput("pass", parsePosition));
    }
```

The recursive method I want to test:

```
bool CElement::parseInput(const std::string& input, unsigned int& parsePosition) {
    static bool checkedForNonASCII = false;
    if(!checkedForNonASCII) {
        std::cout << "this should be printed once for every test case" << std::endl;
        [...]
        checkedForNonASCII = true;
    }
    [...]
    parseInput(input, parsePosition+1)
    [...]
}
```

Since the object is recreated and then destroyed for every test case, I would expect that the string "this should be printed once for every test case" would be printed twice when running the tests, but it's only printed once. What have i missed?

Comment: The object is not recreated and destroyed for each test case. That would happen only if `static` were not specified.

Comment: In any case (1) the `static bool` isn't part of the object, and (2) even if it was it wouldn't be recreated per object. It's static. It retains its value. That's what `static` means.

Comment: If you want a variable initialized each time an object is created, it should be a non-static member that gets initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Also, if you have a recursive function that does something special in the 'first' call, a common pattern is to have a non-recursive wrapper that does the special stuff which then calls a private recursive function that does the real work (and can assume that the special stuff has been done).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what [static local variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) supposed to do.

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

That means `checkedForNonASCII` will be initialized to `false` only once for the 1st call. For further calls the initialization is skipped; i.e. `checkedForNonASCII` won't be initialized to `false` again.

Answer (score 2):

What the other answer said.  But this is probably what you really want:

```
bool CElement::parseInput(const std::string& input, unsigned int& parsePosition)
{
    [...] // your code for validating ascii only characters goes here
    if (hasNonAsciiCharacters) {
       return false;
    }

    return parseInputInteral(input, parsePosition);
}

bool CElement::parseInputInternal(const std::string& input, unsigned int& parsePosition)
{
    [...]
    parseInputInternal(input, parsePosition+1);
    [...]
    return result;
}
```